# How to know if a Future result in a success or failure?

Tags: swift, combine

I have the following `loadData()`:

```
func loadData() -> Future<Void, Error> {
        return Future { promise in
            self.clearResults()
            self.session.request(baseUrl + "/api/v1/pins")
                .responseDecodable(of: [Pin].self) { (response: DataResponse) in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let pins):
                        self.pins = pins
                        promise(.success(()))
                    case .failure(let error):
                        promise(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using it as such, and I'm wondering how I can know whether is successful or failure:

```
self.parent.state
  .loadData()
  .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
    // completion is always invalid when debugging
    switch completion {
    case .failure(let error):
        print("error")
    case .finished:
        print("finish")
    }
}, receiveValue: { value in
    print("Hello")
})
```

Comment: Setting a breakpoint on an empty line doesn't do anything. Try putting something there (e.g `print(123)`), then the breakpoint will stop on it.

Comment: I tried that, and it does not enter there.  let me update above.  thanks!

Comment: It also doesn't look like you're storing the returned `AnyCancellable`, so your subscription is being immediately cancelled.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean?  Sorry first time learning about combine and I am vry confused

Comment: Look at the [documentation for `sink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/sink(receivecompletion:receivevalue:)), particularly its return value

Comment: Thanks so much!   I think I figured it out, one last question is if I have multiple such subscription later, maybe `loadUser()` and `loadProduct()` or something, do I need to make multiple AnyCancellable subscriptions (2 in this case)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219786/discussion-between-alexander-reinstate-monica-and-user1354934).